# Why not run?(Capitalize the first letter of every word)

Tags: javascript

What is the problem with this code?
  I want Capitalize the first letter of every word

```
function capitalizeEachWord(str)
{
   var words = str.split(" ");
   var arr = Array();
   for (i in words)
   {
      temp = words[i].toLowerCase();
      temp = temp.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + temp.substring(1);
      arr.push(temp);
   }
   return arr.join(" ");
      var first=document.getElementById(textbox1).value;
       document.getElementById("resualt").innerHTML=arr; 
     }
```

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Andy More likely the fact he's expecting code in a function *after* a `return` statement to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if id `resualt` is correct. I have set fiddler to test.

```
 document.getElementById("resualt").innerHTML = str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxow8198/)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the function before updating the element.

```
function capitalizeEachWord(str)
{
   var words = str.split(" ");
   var arr = Array();
   for (i in words)
   {
      temp = words[i].toLowerCase();
      temp = temp.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + temp.substring(1);
      arr.push(temp);
   }
   return arr.join(" "); // From now on, it's dead code.
   var first=document.getElementById(textbox1).value;
   document.getElementById("resualt").innerHTML=arr; 
}
```

Try doing this:

```
function capitalizeEachWord(str)
{
   var words = str.split(" ");
   var arr = Array();
   for (i in words)
   {
      temp = words[i].toLowerCase();
      temp = temp.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + temp.substring(1);
      arr.push(temp);
   }
   var strCapitalized = arr.join(" "); // Store it in a variable
   var first=document.getElementById(textbox1).value;
   document.getElementById("resualt").innerHTML = strCapitalized; // Use the variable
}
```

Comment: Or they could try returning the value, then setting the elements innerHTML property as a separate action while calling that function to get the new value. Then they get a useful function that can be used for setting any element, not one that only updates a single one.

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery you can do this as shown below:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cxow8198/3/

```
<input type="text" id="input">

<script>
//usage
$("input").keyup(function() {
   toUpper(this);
});

//function
function toUpper(obj) {
    var mystring = obj.value;
    var sp = mystring.split(' ');
    var wl=0;
    var f ,r;
    var word = new Array();
    for (i = 0 ; i < sp.length ; i ++ ) {
        f = sp[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
        r = sp[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
        word[i] = f+r;
    }
    newstring = word.join(' ');
    obj.value = newstring;
    return true;   
}
</script>
```

Query code snippet to make capitals of the first letter of every word in the string. This could be used to prevent users from entering all caps for titles or text when they input data into forms.